# What's an example of an overloaded 'And' operator in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, operator-overloading

So Google's not a good choice for looking up examples for overloaded operators like "And" or "Or", because it tries to parse them as operators to the search query itself.  MSDN also provides no examples of how to implement an overloaded And operator, so I'm not certain how to properly overload it for my project.

Does anyone have an example of "And" at minimum?  "Or" or "Xor" (or any others) would be a bonus.  I'm not certain if I need to overload these operators in my objects just yet, as I'm still building them out and haven't planned beyond just yet.  But having examples around that might get indexed by Google will probably help save the sanity of a lot of people...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You overload the logical operators in the same way that you overload the unary or arithmetic operators.**

I can't actually think of a case where this would be useful at the moment, but for the sake of example, here's a sample structure that overrides the `And` and `Or` operators:

```
Public Structure Foo

    Public Shared Operator And(ByVal val1 as Foo, ByVal val2 as Foo) As Foo
        ''#(calculate the logical And of the two specified values here)
        Return New Foo(val1.Bar And val2.Bar, val1.Baz And val2.Baz)
    End Operator

    Public Shared Operator Or(ByVal val1 as Foo, ByVal val2 as Foo) As Foo
        ''#(calculate the logical Or of the two specified values here)
        Return New Foo(val1.Bar Or val2.Bar, val1.Baz Or val2.Baz)
    End Operator

End Structure
```

This [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hddt295a.aspx) gives some other examples and further explanation.

Comment: This.  This is what MSDN is missing.  In place of where you put `Return New foo(val1.Bar And val2.Bar ...)`, MSDN has this on the referenced page: `Insert code to calculate And of x and y.`, which is not helpful to me.  I guess it's because I've taken no formal .NET training, but basically relied on Google, SO, and MSDN to learn what I need to build things.  The missing link was the use of `And` itself to test the values Bar and Baz in the comparing objects.  Maybe that's common sense for some, but not everyone.

Comment: Another way to put it, using a word being defined within its own definition.  That's not sensible in normal English thinking, so that's why it didn't dawn on me to use `And` to calculate the And of an object in an overloaded And operator.

Comment: @Kumba: It's worth nothing that this isn't the only way you could implement the calculation. You have to consider what this operation should mean for the objects in your code and write the logic accordingly. For what it's worth, I find myself using operator overloading pretty infrequently, and I've *never* had a need to overload the logical operators.

Comment: Yeah, I don't exactly have a need to overload these just yet (if ever).  But reading into overloading, I was surprised at how little info MSDN gave on specific overloading of the logical operators, and this is basically a case of wanting to know how to in case I find a case during development to implement this type of overloading.  That, and now it'll be enshrined in Google and 15 billion other copycat sites forever and ever, and this will hopefully help a few people from going bonkers over hours of fruitless Google searching.

Comment: @Kumba: Fair enough. It was a good question and got a +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379613%28VS.80%29.aspx) is an article on MSDN explaining operator overloading in VB.NET 2005, this should still be relevant to 2010.

The example for `Add`, from the article (using the `ComplexNumber` class defined in the article):

```
Public Shared Operator +(cn1 As ComplexNumber, _
            cn2 As ComplexNumber) As ComplexNumber

   Dim Result As New ComplexNumber( _
                        cn1.Real() + cn2.Real(), _
                       cn1.Imaginary() + cn2.Imaginary())

   Return Result

End Operator
```

Comment: Yeah, The arithmetic ops I comprehend.  But And/Or/Xor test other things, and when dealing with an object that represents a collection (not a literal VB collection) of various private members and methods, I need to understand what I would test in my object to properly write out an overloaded "And" operator.  Suppose for example that I force my objects to have a "required" field, in such that this field must be set to a valid value for the object to be considered valid.  Would an overloaded "And" operator test that against a second object of the same class and return a boolean result?

Comment: @Kumba - it entirely depends on the object and how you want these operators to operate on it. For some classes it will not even make any sense to even _have_ these operators defined.

Comment: @Oded: That's the problem I have.  There's no solid example (i.e., code) showing what to test inside of an overloaded And operator function so I can look at my objects and decide whether I need to implement those overloads or not.

Comment: @Kumba - It's your code and _you_ have to decide how you want this to operate. No one can decide for you.

Comment: @Oded: I think you misunderstood the intention of my question (or I didn't state it clearly enough -- it is past 6am and I've been up a long time).  I was looking for an example of **how** an And operator is overloaded.  I **know** it's my code, but because no full example of an `And` operater overload exists, I wasn't sure **how** to actually implement that overload.

Comment: @Kumba - Fair enough. I probably did misunderstand.

Comment: And apparently I'm not the only one that's been baffled by this.  That's gotta be the quickest set of up-votes I've had on a question in my short time here...